# How to use SQL (postgresql) query to conditionally change value within each group?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am pretty new to postgresql (or sql), and have not learned how to deal with such "within group" operation. My data is like this:

```
p_id    number
97313   4
97315   10
97315   10
97325   0
97325   15
97326   4
97335   0
97338   0
97338   1
97338   2
97344   5
97345   14
97349   0
97349   5
```

p_id is not unique and can be viewed as a grouping variable. I would like to change the number within each p_id to achieve such operation:

if for a given p_id, one of the value is 0, but any of the other "number" for that pid is >2, then set the 0 value as NULL. Like the "p_id" 97325, there are "0" and "15" associated with it. I will replace the 0 by NULL, and keep the other 15 unchanged.

But for p_id 97338, the three rows associated with it have number "0" "1" "2", therefore I do not replace the 0 by NULL.

The final data should be like:

```
p_id    number
97313   4
97315   10
97315   10
97325   NULL
97325   15
97326   4
97335   0
97338   0
97338   1
97338   2
97344   5
97345   14
97349   NULL
97349   5
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 3):

A `CASE` in a `COUNT OVER` in a `CASE`:

```
SELECT 
p_id, 
(CASE 
 WHEN number = 0 AND COUNT(CASE WHEN number > 2 THEN number END) OVER (PARTITION BY p_id) > 0 
 THEN NULL 
 ELSE number 
 END) AS number
FROM yourtable
```

Test it [here](http://rextester.com/POTQ3564) on rextester.

Comment: This works well, but I do not enough reputation to make my vote publicly viewable. Thanks!

Comment: @J.Z.  Once you approve then you'll receive 5 points I think. And I think you need at least 10 to be able to upvote/downvote

Answer (score 1):

Works for PostgreSQL 10:

```
SELECT p_id, CASE WHEN number = 0 AND maxnum > 2 AND counts >= 2 THEN NULL ELSE number END AS number
FROM
(
SELECT a.p_id AS p_id, a.number AS number, b.maxnum AS maxnum, b.counts AS counts
FROM trans a
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT p_id, MAX(number) AS maxnum, COUNT(1) AS counts
FROM trans
GROUP BY p_id
) b
ON a.p_id = b.p_id
) a1
```

Comment: Welcome! Try formatting your code as a block by indenting it with four spaces, compare https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. That will make your answer easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

use case when

```
 select p_id, 
case when p_id>2 and number=0 then null else number end as number
from yourtable
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/898c3/1

Answer (score 0):

I would express this as:

```
SELECT p_id, 
       (CASE WHEN number <> 0 OR MAX(number) OVER (PARTITION BY p_id) <= 2 
             THEN number 
        END) as number
FROM t;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the fate of a record depends on the existence of other records within (the same or another) table, you could use `EXISTS(...)` :

---

```
UPDATE ztable zt
SET number = NULL
WHERE zt.number = 0
AND EXISTS ( SELECT *
        FROM ztable x
        WHERE x.p_id = zt.p_id
        AND x.number > 2
        );
```